# OpenCV RGB single channel color regulation

Tags: python, opencv, colors, adjustment

Input A image is a full RGB image,
Output B image is a the same image but with "adjusted" R values

I need to rescale the RGB value to be between 128 and 255, so that minor values than 128 are scaled to an upper value.

```
RMAX = 127

img = cv2.imread(filename)         # load img
blue, green, red = cv2.split(img)  # get single color

red = red*RMAX/255+128             # scale the color as I need
```

but this keep getting a wrong value:

if red value is 255 = 255*127/255+128 should output 255 but return 128

Why this happen?

EDIT:

The color values don't need to be recalculated every time, Would it be better to prepare an array at the start with the range of values, then replace the current value with the one from the array?

```
ValuesForRed = [0]*255

for i in range(0,255):
    ValuesForRed[i]=i*127 / 255 + 128
```

how to replace the values in the array is now the problem...

should replace the corresponding value with the corresponding index

```
i.e. red[45]= 0 
     ValuesForRed[0] = 128
     red[45]= 128
```

started new question at 
[Python Opencv cv2.LUT() how to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135984/python-opencv-cv2-lut-how-to-use)

Comment: You can use the suggestion from my second answer. It shows step-by-step method on how to solve the problem in C++. The approach in Python will be similar. The main idea is to use `inRange()` function (available for Python OpenCV) to obtain the mask for the image that specifies the pixels, which value is between 129 and 255 (inclusive). See the second answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because red is `unsigned char`, which is a number in 0 to 255 range. However, you expect `red` to behave like integer.

So given that

```
red = 255
red = red*127/255 + 128
```

When the program multiplies red*127 the result will overflow because its value will be greater than 255, and so the answer will be `0` (because 255*127 modulo 255 = 0). Hence you get `red = red*127/255 + 128 = (255*127 modulo 255) / 255 + 128 = 0 /255 + 128 = 128`

To fix this, you can cast `red` to float when you do arithmetic operations on it, for example:

```
red = (float)red * 127 / 255
```

**Edit**
As pointed out by William `red` is a `cv::Mat` of type `CV_8U`. You can convert the image to `CV_32F` type for calculations and then convert it back. For example (this is C++ code):

```
 Mat red_float;   
 red.convertTo(red_float,CV_32F);
 red_float = red_float*RMAX/255+128;
 red_float.convertTo(red,CV_8U);
```

Comment: Agree. Also an auxiliary cv::Mat with type `CV_32FC3` could be used for calculations and then converted to uchar with convertTo(,CV_8UC3).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, I've tried with int(red * 127 / 255 + 128) but got: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, so I've tried with abs(red * 127 / 255 + 128) but it doesn't do the conversion still got the 128.

Comment: @user2239318 `red` is a matrix. So you'll need to convert the matrix to CV_32F type as described in the second part of the answer (for C++). Since you are using Python, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162359/1121420) might be of help.

Comment: reds = np.int16(red) red= reds* 127 / 255 + 128 make the calculation correctly but when I do a merge of the new colors, I get:cv2.error: /build/opencv-Ai8DTy/opencv-2.4.6.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:286: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function merge

Comment: @user2239318 Your question was "why this happen?". Which I answered. Please tell me in more detail what you are trying to achieve, or edit your question so I can help you better. You can also post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The other question that OP has is "how best to solve this problem?". This is how I would approach it. This is C++ code but you should be able to translate it to Python easily. This approach is fast and there is no need to convert matrices to `CV_32F` type.

- Split input image into channels

  ```
  Mat input_image; //input image
  vector<Mat> split_image(3);
  split(input_image, split_image);
  Mat red = split_image[2];
  ```
- Obtain `mask_red`, such that a location in `mask_red` is set to 255 if the corresponding location in `red` is between 129 and 255 (inclusive bounds), otherwise it is set to 0. This can be achieved with [`inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#cv2.inRange) function.

  ```
  Mat mask_red;
  inRange(red, Scalar(129), Scalar(255), mask_red);
  ```
- Now apply `setTo()` function to `red` to set all masked pixels to 255.

  ```
  red.setTo(Scalar(255), mask_red);
  ```
- Merge the channels to form the final image.

  ```
  Mat output_image;   // output image
  merge(split_image, output_image);
  ```

Comment: actually I need to perform a proportional scaling, inRange seems to return 255 if it's in the range, something like a true if verified, not a proportional scaling, if 0:128, if 3:129 etc...