# Python Opencv cv2.LUT() how to use

Tags: python, opencv, methods

Need to apply some rapid conversion on the color channels of a image.

1)I have stored in a list the corresponding output value:

```
ListaVred = [0]*255

for i in range(0,255):
    ListaVred[i]=i*127 / 255 + 128
```

2)I get the color input value from 0 to 255 from the image

3)should replace in the image the input values with the output

```
i.e. red[45]= 0 
     ListaVred0] = 128
     red[45]= 128
```

I've looked at cv2.LUT(src,dst) function but not sure about it's use, 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.LUT

```
cv2.LUT(ListaVred,red)
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar


ListaVred = np.array(ListaVred)
cv2.LUT(ListaVred,red)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-Ai8DTy/opencv-2.4.6.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:1195: error: (-215) (lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) && lut.total() == 256 && lut.isContinuous() && (src.depth() == CV_8U || src.depth() == CV_8S) in function LUT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You looked into documentation of yet to be released version of OpenCV (version 3.0). I guess you are using OpenCV 2.4.8 or lower. Check [this documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut). Notice the differences in usage of LUT function. At the top of the page you will see the version of OpenCV to which this documentation belong.

```
LUT(srcImage, lookupTable, dstImage)
```