# How to convert a 16-bit to an 8-bit image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a 16-bit grayscale image and I want to convert it to an 8-bit grayscale image in OpenCV for Python to use it with various functions (like `findContours` etc.). How can I do this in Python?

Comment: In c++ its done with .convertTo . Maybe you can find it with this information. In addition if you want to convert to binary (e.g. for findContours)  a simple > 0 operation might do the trick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162227/python-opencv-matconvertto-in-python

Comment: @Micka Even if I change the image depth with the methods you mentioned, OpenCV will still treat the image as a 16-bit image.

Comment: sorry, can't help with python openCv. Only got experience with c++ openCV.

Answer (score 28):

You can use numpy conversion methods as an OpenCV mat is a numpy array.

This works:

```
img8 = (img16/256).astype('uint8')
```

Comment: for processing purposes you can add another notch with:
    `ratio = np.amax(im16) / 256 ; 
     img8 = (im16 / ratio).astype('uint8')`

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can in Python. To get the expected result, choose a method based on what you want the values mapped from say uint16 to uint8 be.

For instance,

if you do    `img8 = (img16/256).astype('uint8')` values below 256 are mapped to 0

if you do    `img8 = img16.astype('uint8')` values above 255 are mapped to 0

In the LUT method as described and corrected above, you have to define the mapping.

Answer (score 4):

Opencv provides the function `cv2.convertScaleAbs()`

```
image_8bit = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=0.03)
```

Alpha is just a optional scale factor. Also works for multiple channel images.

OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d):

> Scales, calculates absolute values, and converts the result to 8-bit.

> On each element of the input array, the function convertScaleAbs
> performs three operations sequentially: scaling, taking an absolute
> value, conversion to an unsigned 8-bit type:

Other Info on Stackoverflow: [OpenCV: How to use the convertScaleAbs() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231962/opencv-how-to-use-the-convertscaleabs-function)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Python using NumPy by mapping the image trough a lookup table.

```
import numpy as np


def map_uint16_to_uint8(img, lower_bound=None, upper_bound=None):
    '''
    Map a 16-bit image trough a lookup table to convert it to 8-bit.

    Parameters
    ----------
    img: numpy.ndarray[np.uint16]
        image that should be mapped
    lower_bound: int, optional
        lower bound of the range that should be mapped to ``[0, 255]``,
        value must be in the range ``[0, 65535]`` and smaller than `upper_bound`
        (defaults to ``numpy.min(img)``)
    upper_bound: int, optional
       upper bound of the range that should be mapped to ``[0, 255]``,
       value must be in the range ``[0, 65535]`` and larger than `lower_bound`
       (defaults to ``numpy.max(img)``)

    Returns
    -------
    numpy.ndarray[uint8]
    '''
    if not(0 <= lower_bound < 2**16) and lower_bound is not None:
        raise ValueError(
            '"lower_bound" must be in the range [0, 65535]')
    if not(0 <= upper_bound < 2**16) and upper_bound is not None:
        raise ValueError(
            '"upper_bound" must be in the range [0, 65535]')
    if lower_bound is None:
        lower_bound = np.min(img)
    if upper_bound is None:
        upper_bound = np.max(img)
    if lower_bound >= upper_bound:
        raise ValueError(
            '"lower_bound" must be smaller than "upper_bound"')
    lut = np.concatenate([
        np.zeros(lower_bound, dtype=np.uint16),
        np.linspace(0, 255, upper_bound - lower_bound).astype(np.uint16),
        np.ones(2**16 - upper_bound, dtype=np.uint16) * 255
    ])
    return lut[img].astype(np.uint8)


# Let's generate an example image (normally you would load the 16-bit image: cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
img = (np.random.random((100, 100)) * 2**16).astype(np.uint16)

# Convert it to 8-bit
map_uint16_to_uint8(img)
```

Comment: `+1` for an answer, though the other one is quicker :) I wonder if it's possible  just to use `.clip(lb, ub)` somehow, since it handles `None` nicely?

Comment: @uhoh `clip()` won't handle the case where `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are both `None`. `img.clip(None, None)` raises `ValueError: array_clip: must set either max or min`

Comment: Rats! That's a good point. I'm surprised by that; I wonder why it was decided to not handle that case. The two values could come from different places and not know about each other ahead of time. In matplotlib `plt.xlim(None, None)` works fine for example. OK I will keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: had to modify here:     if lower_bound is not None:
        if not(0 <= lower_bound < 2**16):
            raise ValueError(
                '"lower_bound" must be in the range [0, 65535]')
    if upper_bound is not None:
        if not(0 <= upper_bound < 2**16):
            raise ValueError(
                '"upper_bound" must be in the range [0, 65535]')

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy to convert to 8-bit using scipy.misc.bytescale. The OpenCV matrix is a numpy array, so bytescale will do exactly what you want.

```
from scipy.misc import bytescale
img8 = bytescale(img16)
```

Comment: `bytescale` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.

Comment: This has been replaced by skimage.util.img_as_ubyte

Answer (score 2):

Code from scipy (now deprecated):

```
def bytescaling(data, cmin=None, cmax=None, high=255, low=0):
    """
    Converting the input image to uint8 dtype and scaling
    the range to ``(low, high)`` (default 0-255). If the input image already has 
    dtype uint8, no scaling is done.
    :param data: 16-bit image data array
    :param cmin: bias scaling of small values (def: data.min())
    :param cmax: bias scaling of large values (def: data.max())
    :param high: scale max value to high. (def: 255)
    :param low: scale min value to low. (def: 0)
    :return: 8-bit image data array
    """
    if data.dtype == np.uint8:
        return data

    if high > 255:
        high = 255
    if low < 0:
        low = 0
    if high < low:
        raise ValueError("`high` should be greater than or equal to `low`.")

    if cmin is None:
        cmin = data.min()
    if cmax is None:
        cmax = data.max()

    cscale = cmax - cmin
    if cscale == 0:
        cscale = 1

    scale = float(high - low) / cscale
    bytedata = (data - cmin) * scale + low
    return (bytedata.clip(low, high) + 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way I found: `img8 = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)`

Comment: Please use  **`**  in both start and end of the code to make it look like `this`, if the code is big, use **4 spaces** or use **```** at both start and end of code.