# Why does histogram equalization on a 16-bit image show a strange result?

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a 16-bit image which I want to rescale to 8-bit while achieving a high contrast. Now I tried histogram equalization as follows:

```
image_equ = cv.equalizeHist(cv_image.astype(np.uint8))
```

But the output is super strange:

[image: Results]

What is happening? Is the rescaling to 8-bit first maybe the problem?

Comment: How does .astype(np.uint8)) work? I guess there is no scaling performed but only reinterpretation and maybe saturation. Can you try to multiply all pixels by 255/65535 before .astype?

Comment: 'cv_image = cv.equalizeHist(((cv_image*255/65535).astype(np.uint8)))' than the image is completely black:

Comment: @Micka divind by x and looking into the intensity histogram I can see large gaps, which only get larger with higher number

Comment: You must scale the values after histEqualization. Can you read the min and max pixel values after histogram equalization?

Comment: `astype(uint8)` doesn't "rescale". it just chops the upper bits off (no saturation math), practically, and that causes wraparound, as can be seen in the picture -- `equalizeHist` can only deal with 8-bit values. you'll have to scale them before. make sure the intermediate result (image*255) has a suitable type and doesn't wrap around. better yet, parenthesize like `image * (255/65535)` because python will make a float of that

Comment: Related: [How to convert a 16 bit to an 8 bit image in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485886/how-to-convert-a-16-bit-to-an-8-bit-image-in-opencv) (does not explain *why* it looks strange though, only shows *how* to do it correctly)

Comment: Such "banding" is typical of overflow of the data type. In particular, when trying to store 16 bits in 8 bits, every multiple of 256 will fall back on 0, causing strong discontinuities. [Being in the field since many years, I don' find it super strange; rather routinely occurring ;-) ]

Answer (score 4):

`cv2.equalizeHist` does not support `uint16` input, and `cv_image.astype(np.uint8)` results overflows.
The solution is using different library, or implement the equalization using NumPy.

We can find the NumPy implementation of `uint8` equalization in the OpenCV documentation:
[Histograms - 2: Histogram Equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)

We can adjust the code (using NumPy) for `uint16` input and output:

- Replace `256` with `65536` (256 = 2^8 and 65536 = 2^16).
- Replace `255` with `65535`.
- Replace `uint8` with `uint16`.

---

Assuming the original code is correct, the following should work for `uint16`:

```python
hist, bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(), 65536, [0, 65536])  # Collect 16 bits histogram (65536 = 2^16).
cdf = hist.cumsum()

cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf, 0)  # Find the minimum histogram value (excluding 0)
cdf_m = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*65535/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_m,0).astype('uint16')

# Now we have the look-up table...
img2 = cdf[img]
```

---

Complete code sample (building sample 16 bits input):

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Build sample input for testing.
################################################################################
img = cv2.imread('chelsea.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read sample input image.
cv2.imshow('img', img)  # Show input for testing.
img = img.astype(np.uint16) * 16 + 1000  # Make the image 16 bit, but the pixels range is going to be [1000, 5080] not full range (for example).
################################################################################

#equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img) # error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::equalizeHist'

# https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html
hist, bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(), 65536, [0, 65536])  # Collect 16 bits histogram (65536 = 2^16).
cdf = hist.cumsum()

cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf, 0)  # Find the minimum histogram value (excluding 0)
cdf_m = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*65535/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_m,0).astype('uint16')

# Now we have the look-up table...
equ = cdf[img]

# Show result for testing.
cv2.imshow('equ', equ)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Input (before scaling to 16 bits):
[image]

Output:
[image]