# Saving floating point image as PNG in OpenCV (python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm applying an unsharp filter to an image using dft and a Butterworth filter. If you are not familiar with the process, you transform the image to its DFT (cv2.dft), multiply by it the Butterworth filter (search on Wikipedia) then inverse the DFT (cv2.idft). This way you obtain a lowpass filtered image. Then you do a weighted sum of the original image and the lowpass image and you obtain your goal image (just as you would do when applying any unsharp filter).

As you can see, I need to operate with floating point images.

I have been able to complete the process correctly, and I get the desired result when using `imshow`, but now I want to save the result to a PNG file. To do that, I need to convert the floating point image to a uint8 format, but doing so doesn't yield the same result as seen with `imshow`.

The max value of the floating point image is 1.8, so that means it is not normalized after applying the sum. I try to normalize (`NORM_MINMAX`) it, multiply by 255 and converting to `uint8`, but the result is still different than what is seen with imshow.

EDIT: images

Original image
[image]

Processed (without normalizing)
[image]

Processed (normalizing)
[image]

Desired result (screenshot of imshow)
[image]

(I'd like to share more example images, but I can't attach any more links)

Is there any way to do the exact same process that `imshow` does on the floating point image for saving it? It must be converting it to `uint8` format internally, doesn't it?

Comment: You must multiply by `255/1.8` surely? The result image you have shown has the black point set too high, i.e. the darkest pixel is not zero.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's the result when multiplying the NORMALIZED image by 255, so the max value in that case is 1.0 . I wanted to show the different results I get, but as I said I can't attach any more images

Comment: There seems to be also an _unwanted_ border in second image

Comment: Can you provide your processed image? a link to the YAML file should be ok.

Comment: Also I think that for float32 images, `imshow` just do: `Mat1f processed_image; ... ; Mat3b img; processed_image.convertTo(img, CV_8U, 255.0);`. well this is C++, but you should be ok just converting and scaling. Values grater the 1 wuold be saturated to 255

Comment: @Miki You are right, I corrected it. Sadly, there's no difference in the result

Comment: try avoiding normalization

Comment: @Miki I replaced the images with an imgur album with more results. And well, I'm trying to replicate the same effect as the one in C++ you described, but it's certainly not working. The resources online for OpenCV in Python are limited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162227/python-opencv-matconvertto-in-python . Then I think you need to saturate values manually