# error: (-215) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function equalizeHist when trying to equalize a float64 image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to equalize a 1 one channel image like so:

```
img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
```

But since it's a float64 img, I get the following error:

> error: (-215) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function equalizeHist

How do I go about this?

Comment: is it an option to convert it to 8UC1?

Comment: Is 8UC1 a binary image that will give me just black and white pixels? If so, then unfortunately, no.

Comment: no it is integer ranging from 0 to 255, which is standard range for each channel in RGB images. Depends on your problem whethrr the loss og precision is ok. Why do you have float64 type?

Comment: In that case how do I convert it to 8UC1?

Comment: img.convertTo(dst, CV_8UC1) is the c++ syntax. not sure about python, sorry. make sure that your value range is within 0..255 before conversion and not within 0..1

Comment: Thanks. Is 8UC1 same as uint8? Here are the available dtypes in python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtxt

Comment: should be. 8uc1 means 8 bit unsigned integer type with 1 channel.

Comment: Because I've already tried uint8, and I get a completely black image.

Comment: please make sure that values are in range 0..255 before conversion. typically float types interpret 0 as black and 1 as white and everything in between as grayscale. if you convert that to integer type you will get only values 0 (black) and maybe 1 (nearly black). try to mulitply the whole image by 255 before conversion please

Comment: Great, thanks! Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function equalizeHist is histogram equalization of images and only implemented for CV_8UC1 type, which is a single channel 8 bit unsigned integral type.

To convert your image to this type you can use the function `convertTo` with the target type (must be the same number of channels).

Make sure that the source image has the right value range, typically floating point images are interpreted as 0 = black and 1 = white and the gray range is in between, while integer images are interpreted as 0 = black and maximum value = white (which would be 255 for unsigned 8 bit type). So you'll often have to multiply your source image by 255 to fit the range. Function `convertTo` has a parameter to scale your values during conversion, which could give you a speed improvement compared to manual scaling.

Comment: where is this method `convertTo` ? it is not in `cv2` afaict

Comment: sorry, I only know the c++ syntax. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162227/python-opencv-matconvertto-in-python

Comment: ok thanks i was trying `np.uint8(img)`   But i still get same error.

Answer (score 11):

so basically histogram equalize is work with gray scaled images.
so if you want to do histogram equalize at colorful image you can use this code.

```
R, G, B = cv2.split(img)

output1_R = cv2.equalizeHist(R)
output1_G = cv2.equalizeHist(G)
output1_B = cv2.equalizeHist(B)

equ = cv2.merge((output1_R, output1_G, output1_B))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use **.astype**(numpy.uint8).

Answer (score 2):

When initialising your image variable, don't forget the flag, that solved it for me.

```
img = cv2.imread("my_image.png", 0)
```

I used 0 as the flag because I was working with a greyscale image.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the image and converting it to gray. Use 
`img = np.float32(img)`