# Datatype error in opencv function equalizeHist

Tags: python, opencv

Given an image read in by `cv2.readimg()` as follows:

```
cv2.imread(path)
```

and then invoking `cv2.equalizeHist` the following error is happening:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    hist = cv2.equalizeHist(cv_image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:3345: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'equalizeHist'
```

I have read and applied answers from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764885/error-215-src-type-cv-8uc1-in-function-equalizehist-when-trying-to-equ) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260601/convert-image-from-cv-64f-to-cv-8u) one. Here is the code applied from the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46260702/1056563) answer :

```
  import cv2
  removedNoise = cv2.medianBlur(img,3)
  removedNoise1 = np.uint8(removedNoise)
  hist = cv2.equalizeHist(cv_image)
```

Here is the same code modified for trying the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48513217/1056563) answer :

```
  from skimage import img_as_ubyte
  cv_image = img_as_ubyte(removedNoise)
  hist = cv2.equalizeHist(cv_image)
```

In both cases the same original error is occurring. Advice on how to address this would be appreciated. I am using `opencv 4.1.0` on `macos`.

Comment: can you upload the image that gives the error.?

Comment: Can you try reading the image like this, `img = cv2.imread(path, 0); hist = cv2.equalizeHist(img)`

Comment: @SreeramTP adding the `,0` parameter seems to have fixed it- please make an answer.

Comment: on it. I will add the explaination along with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equalizeHist` in opencv takes argument `src` where `src` is expected to be a 8bit single channel image.

In your code, you are reading the image as 3 channel image or BGR. You can read the image as GrayScale like this,

```
img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
```

Passing this image to `equalizeHist` like shown below will give the desired output.

```
hist = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=equalizehist) for more details.

The `0` in the `imread` is a flag indicating the color type of the image. You can read more about the `flags` [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread).

Comment: `cv2.imread(path, 0)` -- same as the other answer, please don't suggest using magic numbers. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80ae29981cfc153d3b0cef5c0daeedd2125

Comment: Almost same as other answer: I upvoted both.  Hard to choose among them  I made tie-breaker the other one was a little sooner.

Comment: But i gave you the solution first via comment. Well, it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 2):

The attached traceback states that:

> (-215:Assertion failed) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'equalizeHist'

Which states that the input argument to `cv2. equalizeHist()` must be a single channel image. By default `cv2.imread()` returns a 3 channel BGR image, even if the image is grayscale in nature. You can try one of following suggestions to fix this error:

1. `cv2.imread("path/to/img.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`
2. `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: `cv2.imread("path/to/img.png", 0)` -- Come on, i'm sure you know better than to suggest using magic numbers when there's a nice named constant provided.

Comment: Not on my IDE:P

Comment: Then your IDE is misconfigured, See the docs: [`cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80ae29981cfc153d3b0cef5c0daeedd2125) It's been there since 3.0 (and ones with different names before).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Python Wand (which is based upon Imagemagick)?  Here is an example of histogram equalization in just a few lines of code.

Input:

[image]

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='zelda.png') as img:
    img.equalize()
    img.save(filename='zelda_equalize.png')
```

[image]