# How to convert any image to CV_32FC1 in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have code in C++ for converting an image to "CV_32FC1" but I want to do same thing in Python. Here is my C++ code.

```
img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);
```

How can I do same thing in Python?

Comment: Possibly relevant link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16162227/11301900.

Answer (score 4):

Python uses `numpy` to manage the image pixel data, you can do something like this in numpy to change the data type of a matrix:

```
img = img.astype("float32")
```

As added by @HansHirse in the comments, this operation will just change the data type of the matrix, but if you want to change the scale of pixel values then you should use `img = img.astype("float32")/255`, to convert all the pixel values in range `0.0 - 1.0`

Comment: I just tested the C++ API's `convertTo`, and I remembered incorrectly. Actually, `convertTo` doesn't scale automatically, but will also just change the data type. So, the plain `.astype` will correctly mimic the behaviour of `convertTo`.

Comment: @HansHirse I’m not familiar with OpenCV, do you know if [`cvtColor()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) would work?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile From the documentation: _**dst** – output image of the same size and depth as `src`._ So, no – type casts aren't supposed to be done with `cv2.cvtColor`.

Comment: @Zdar this is CV_32FC1 mean float channel one so if we convert it to float 32 in numpy the no of channel will remain same. so what is solution for that??

Comment: @ParagJain Pardon? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile i  have not worked with image more so i want to know like "CV_32FC1" this data type  will convert image to float as well as in one channel but the solution given above which is in python will convert image only into float but no of channel will remain same as per my knowledge.

Comment: @ParagJain I’m not sure, but there’s a simple way to find out: look at the NumPy output from an image with multiple channels, try a conversion, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile got it!! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0a353a4b8db9040165db4dacb5bcefb6ea

You can use the function

```
 cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```